# How do I use PHP to display confirmation tracking code only once w/o using a database?

Tags: php

How do I make it so the tracking code only runs once...and isn't triggered again on a refresh?

I searched but it seems almost always people are saying to use a database...but I was hoping to avoid that....is it possible?

Thanks

here is the solution for future searchers:

before `<HTML>` put: `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Then do this:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['check']!=1)
{
$_SESSION['check']=1;
echo '<div class="show">tracking code</div>';}
?>
```

Comment: What tracking code? What are you trying to do? What code have you written?

Comment: And why don't you want to use a database?  Databases are for storing data.  You have data to store.

Comment: it's affiliate tracking code and the reason I don't want to use a database, is because it feels like overkill to store a single data point

Comment: Try out a database that isn't overkill, like SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options available to accomplish this. You can use a flag variable in $_SESSION, you can use in-browser storage with HTML5, or a Javascript DB like http://taffydb.com/. $_SESSION flag variables would probably be the easiest since it doesn't require you to research much more than you already know.

Good luck!